# How to use Rules to populate reference product after creating a Commerce product?

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

After a Commerce product is created I need to create a new product display node and reference the product in a field.

This is my first time using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules). I can create a new product display node but I cant figure out how to populate the 'referenced product' field.

Comment: I would steer clear of this.  There are likely to be situations where you're going to be creating a product that you don't want a display for (i.e. small t-shirt, med t-shirt = 2 products/1 display).

I'd be more inclined to do it the other way round using [Inline Entity Form](http://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) and create products and displays at the same time.

Comment: No, my product and product displays will always have a 1 to 1 relationship. I want it to work the way around that ive described so you can administer products from the normal product admin views.

Comment: If you use the IEF then you can still administer products from the normal product admin screen.  Visually you're only creating one piece of content.  It'll be more robust than Rules and allow for future-proofing.

Comment: However i would still like to know the answer to my question even if its just to improve my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the limited information in your question, you should be able to create such rule (using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module) like so:

- Use a Rules **Event** that is related to "When Commerce product is created" (something similar to "After saving content"?).
- Add a Rules **Condition** to make your `referenced product` field become available to use in a Rules **Action**. This condition can be either of those alternatives:

  - "Entity has field".
  - "Content is of type".
- Add Rules **Action** "Set a data value" for your `referenced product` field.